# Xamarin.iOS does not recognize the 'Bitmap' type from the referenced System.Drawing.Common

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, .net-standard-2.0

With Visual Studio 15.8.1 on Windows (running on a mac using `Parallels`), I have created an iOS application using Xamarin.iOS targeting iOS 11.4. To build the application, I have set up a build agent on macOS that is running the latest Xamarin 11.14.0.11.

Then I have created a new `.netstandard 2.0` library that references Microsoft's NuGet package `System.Drawing.Common`.

In that library, I have added the following class:

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace library
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        private readonly Bitmap m_bitmap;

        public SomeClass(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            m_bitmap = bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

The library is then referenced by the iOS project and everything is building just fine.

In the `ViewController` of the iOS project, I have added the following code that uses the previous class and added a references to the `System.Drawing.Common` package to be able to use the `Bitmap` class:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    private SomeClass m_someClass;

    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        m_someClass = new SomeClass(new System.Drawing.Bitmap());
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now, it is failing to build and I get the following error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> error CS7069: Reference to type 'Bitmap' claims it is
>   defined in 'System.Drawing.Common', but it could not be found

**Question**

I followed [the answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915844/can-not-use-system-drawing-common-in-mono-android-and-xamarin-ios). Everything is up-to-date (Visual Studio & Xamarin on macOS). I tried to manually copy `System.Drawing.Common` from the `.netstandard20` of the package to the output as well as adding the DLL directly to the project as a reference. I never got anything working.

What should be done?

Comment: Can you share a repro solution for this?

Comment: @AlexGhiondea-MSFT Well, everything that I put in the question is the repro steps. My actual solution involves a lot more projects but I have been able to reproduce the issue with the two described project: a .netstandard 2.0 project with the specified class, referenced by a Xamarin.iOS application. Both of them are referencing the System.Drawing.Common NuGet package (and nothing more... no other DLL manually added).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get a local repro. It looks like you are following up on this in the Mono repo: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/10310

Comment: @AlexGhiondea-MSFT True. I originally opened the bug to the CoreFX team few hours after asking the question here on SO but got redirected to the mono team.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Project reference folder
2. Click on Add Reference
3. In the .NET tab you will find `System.Drawing`
4. Click on OK. This will add a reference to `System.Drawing`

Comment: This would be the way to go if I was working with the .net framework. But I am not.

Comment: maybe this is useful to you  https://github.com/CoreCompat/System.Drawing